# JNI - FATAL ERROR in native method: Bad global or local ref passed to JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jnienv

I checked the related questions on this error, but couldn't find the answer.
I have the following code. The error is related to calling jLog method and if I take it out the error is gone, so I don't understand what is the problems - just my first experience with JNI:

```
static jclass util_class;
static jmethodID log_from_jni;
...
    util_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "package/Util");
    if ((*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env)) {
        printf("Error occured when loading Util class\n");
    }
    log_from_jni = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, util_class,
            "logFromJNI", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    if ((*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env)) {
        printf("Error occured when loading logFromJNI method\n");
    }
...

void jLog(JNIEnv *env, char* cstr) {
    if (util_class != NULL || log_from_jni != NULL) {
        jstring str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, cstr);
        (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, util_class, log_from_jni, str);
    } else {
        printf(cstr);
    }

}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_package_callLog(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {\
    jLog(env, "JNI: Log");//
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I guess `package.Util` is a typo for `package/Util` ?

Comment: yes, it was a typo. sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `jclass` is just another Java heap object, which means it can be moved by the garbage collector, which would make the `utill_class` that you saved basically a dangling pointer.

If you want a `jclass` that stays valid, you need to create a global reference for it:

```
util_class = (jclass) (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, (*env)->FindClass(env, "package/Util"));
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have worked! I knew it was a simple thing, but being a total beginner with JNI I couldn't figure it out. I up-voted but it won't show as I have the low reputation.

Comment: To have a clear understanding, if the `util_class` is defined as global reference, then it also needs to be deleted once it is not needed, right?

Comment: @xtcr1st1 Yes. Local references get deleted automatically at the end of a JNI call (unless they are returned afaik). But global references need to be managed manually. (Though if you use something for the entire duration of the application it doesn't really matter, since it gets cleaned up by the OS after the application finishes).

Comment: A JNI local reference would be deleted regardless but, if returned, whatever object it refers to would stay alive as long as needed, just like being returned from a Java method.